# I'm getting a final link error when I compile a c program

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm writing this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(){

    int fd[2];

    pid_t pid;
    pipe(fd);

    pid = fork();

    if(pid>0)
    {
        while(1){
            char * command = (char*)malloc(55);

            printf("Command: ");
            fgets(command,55,stdin);

            write(fd[1],&command,55);

            wait(NULL);
        }
        
    }
    else if(pid)
    {
        char * command = (char*)malloc(55);
        read(fd[0],&command,55);

        printf("Child command: %s",command);
        

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

and when I compile I'll get this error: [image: error]

I can't figure out what could be. I know that I'm not using all libraries and checking for errors but i think that's not the issue here. Thanks! Have a great day!

Comment: How are you compiling the program?

Comment: @user253751 gcc name.c -o name. Something like this

Comment: I tried compiling your code using `gcc name.c` and `gcc name.c -o name.exe` and both worked. Mind you, I'm using cygwin on Windows to compile it.

Comment: Your `name.exe` application is running, so the executable file is in use and cannot be overwritten. Make sure it terminates (or kill it) before compiling it.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni thanks!

Comment: Was it the actual reason? Happy to help.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni sorry for late response, but yeah that was the reason